# Cygwin: Couldn't determine name of user running sshd service from account database

Tags: ssh, cygwin, sftp

I've been following a tutorial on youtube here:  [SFTP Setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXzBdVXjKGU)

And I've been following all the steps exactly but I've run into a problem in Cygwin while trying to install SSH.

Upon opening the Cygwin64 Terminal I typed the following

```
$ export CYGWIN='ntsec tty'
$ chmod 0755 /var
$ ssh-host-config
```

Then I get to the questions

The first question is `Should StrictModes be used? (yes/no)` where I type `no`.  The next question is `Should privilege separation be used? (yes/no)` where I type `yes`.

Then I get the following error/warning (Regardless of whether I select `no` or `yes`):

```
*** Warning: Couldn't determine name of user running sshd service from account database!
*** Warning: As a result, this script cannot make sure that the files used
*** Warning: by the sshd service belong to the user running the service.

*** Warning: Host configuration exited with 1 errors or warnings!
*** Warning: Make sure that all problems reported are fixed,
*** Warning: then re-run ssh-host-config
```

I'm not sure how to resolve these errors!  What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message refers to the "user running sshd service". It occurs because there is already an sshd service owned by a different user, (for me it was created by the Windows 10 OpenSSH optional feature).

If you delete the old service and try again, it should work.

You can delete the service with sc, for example: `sc.exe delete sshd`.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the CYGWIN settings you are using are obsolete, see:

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html

So likely almost all the tutorial. About

> Should StrictModes be used? (yes/no)

The default is `Yes` so don't use different value.

Comment: Same problem still exists when I say `yes` to `Should StrictModes be used? (yes/no)`

Comment: please provide the output of `$ /usr/bin/cygrunsrv -VQ sshd` .You can also  follow `https://cygwin.com/problems.html` and ship there the cygcheck.out

Comment: Nevermind, I'm sorry it did actually work, thanks man you're a life saver!